# Fairness post-processing changing threshold and margin

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I have a doubt, I want to use fairness methods and I see the tutorial they split test into test and validation and use validation to determine the best threshold and margin for predictions. But I implemented nested cross validation using pipelines and I do not have to split the validation so I do not see the index for validation

```
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, cv=cv_inner, scoring=opt_score,verbose=10, refit=True)
```

Can I compute the threshold using the training set? to use the new threshold for the test set. Or the best solution is to get the best estimator, and obtain only the parameters and split again in this case train val and test and perform the threshold only in val and use only the nested to select the best parameters.

Thank you very much